# Unknown option -D Gjs

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, gnome, gjs

Gjs documentation says `gjs -D -S example.js` will start a debugger but when I do the same follow error occurs

```sh
$ gjs -D test.js

(gjs:26381): Gjs-ERROR **: 06:18:06.759: option parsing failed: Unknown option -D
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 with gnome 3.28.2 and Gjs 1.52.5.

Comment: I also tried lowercase i.e `$gjs -d test.js` but it also didn't worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new debugger is only available in `gjs >= 1.53.90` or the stable release `1.54.0` shipped with GNOME 3.30.

For a detailed list of when features are shipped and in what version, see https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gjs/blob/master/NEWS.